# Passing a string argument to a function - why isn't it working?

Tags: python, string, function

Trying to pass a string argument to a function, which will then be used as a variable throughout the function. For some reason, when I am trying to do this, it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
import subprocess
def printerSetup(printer):
    subprocess.call(r'Cscript c:/windows/System32/Printing_Admin_Scripts/en-US/Prnport.vbs -a -r "'printer'.print.web.com" -h "' + printer + '.print.web.com" -o raw')
    if printer == 'saturn' or printer == 'jupiter' or printer == 'neptune':
        subprocess.call(r'rundll32 printui.dll, PrintUIEntry /if /b "' + printer + '" /f w:\printers\toshibae3511\eng\est_c2.inf /r "' + printer + '.print.web.com" /m "TOSHIBA e-STUDIO Color PS3"')
    if printer == 'mercury':
        subprocess.call(r'rundll32 printui.dll, PrintUIEntry /if /b "' + printer + '" /f w:\printers\dell1720\drivers\print\dell1720\DKABJ740.inf /r "' + printer + '.print.web.com" /m "Dell Laser Printer 1720dn"')

printerSetup("neptune")
printerSetup("mercury")
```

Edited the program. After trying to run this new one, get this error:

```
C:\Python27\Projects\Printer Setup>c:\python27\python.exe saturn.py
  File "saturn.py", line 3
    subprocess.call(r'Cscript c:/windows/System32/Printing_Admin_Scripts/en-US/P
rnport.vbs -a -r "'printer'.print.web.com" -h "' + printer + '.print.web.c
om" -o raw')

                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please specify in what way it isn't working. Are you trying to get the value of the `printer` argument into argument of the first `subprocess.call()` line?

Comment: In what sense is it not working?

Comment: You need colons after if statements.

Comment: `if printer == 'saturn' or 'jupiter' or 'neptune'` you forgot some `printer ==` here

Comment: as far as I was thinking, "string"variable"string" should insert the variable into the string, but I'd have to use +, now wouldn't I.

Comment: You forgot to put the '+' operator while using the variable. Like this: `subprocess.call(r'Cscript c:/windows/System32/Printing_Admin_Scripts/en-US/Prnport.vbs -a -r "'+printer+'.print.mediag.com" -h "'+printer+'.print.mediag.com" -o raw')
` Try the same for the other statements

Comment: Sorry for the silliness of this question, been about 6 months since I programmed in Python, it's fading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify `variable == value` for each `or` statement, like so:

```
if printer == 'saturn' or printer == 'jupiter' or printer == 'neptune':
```

You also forgot the trailing colon on each `if` statement.

If you want to say "does this variable match this list of values?", the following might be cleaner for you:

```
if printer in ('saturn', 'jupiter', 'neptune'):
```

You also need to add variables to strings - you can't just place them adjacent:

```
'string' + variable + 'string'

 # not

 'string'variable'string'
```

Comment: You can add strings together that way, though, but not with variables `'string' 'string'`